# Removing rows with NaN in MultiIndex with duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, multi-index

**Updated with a DataFrame that repros my exact issue**

I have an issue where `NaN` appearing in my indexes is leading to non-unique rows (since `NaN !== NaN`). I need to drop all rows where `NaN` occurs in the index. My previous question had an example DataFrame with a single `NaN` row, however the original solution did not resolve my issue as it did not meet this poorly advertised requirement:

> (Note that in the actual data I have thousands of such rows, including duplicate rows since `NaN !== NaN` so this is permissible on an index)

(from my original post)

### The Issue

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,"a"],[1,2,"b"],[1,3,"c"],[1,np.nan,"x"],[1,np.nan,"x"],[1,np.nan,"x"],[2,1,"d"],[2,2,"e"],[np.nan,1,"x"],[np.nan,2,"x"],[np.nan,1,"x"]], columns=["a","b","c"])
>>>df
         c
a   b
1.0 1.0  a
    2.0  b
    3.0  c
    NaN  x
    NaN  x
    NaN  x
2.0 1.0  d
    2.0  e
NaN 1.0  x
    2.0  x
    1.0  x
```

Note the duplicate rows: `(1.0, NaN)` and `(NaN, 1.0)`

### Failed Solutions:

I've tried something simple like:

```
>>>df = df[pandas.notnull(df.index)]
```

But this fails because `notnull` is not implemented for MultiIndex.

Also one of the early answers suggested:

```
>>>df = df.reindex(df.index.dropna())
```

However this failed with the error:

```
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

### Desired Output:

```
>>>df
         c
a   b
1.0 1.0  a
    2.0  b
    3.0  c
2.0 1.0  d
    2.0  e
```

(all `NaN` index rows are dropped, eliminating any non-unique rows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**
*`reset_index`*, *`dropna`*, and *`set_index`* once more.

```
c = df.index.names
df = df.reset_index().dropna().set_index(c)
df

         c
a   b     
1.0 1.0  a
    2.0  b
    3.0  c
2.0 1.0  d
    2.0  e
    2.0  x
    1.0  x
```

---

If your `MultiIndex` is unique, you can use...
**Option 2**
*`df.index.dropna`* and *`df.reindex`*

```
df = df.reindex(df.index.dropna())
```

Comment: This is giving me the error: `cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`. The whole reason I wanted to drop these rows, though, was being it was creating non-unique multi-indexes (where `NaN !== NaN`). I'll update the question with a DataFrame that repros my issue.

Comment: @stevendesu The other method (not reindex) works nicely with your new output.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Can confirm, tried the other option and it worked :) Thank you

Comment: If you want to keep NaN-valued records (in contrast with NaN only in the initial multi-index), don't forget to specify where the NaN are to be filtered out by calling `.dropna(subset=['<level_with_nan>'])`.