# How to convert multilevel index to columns in Python. (IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes.)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (named = energy) which looks like this (Please refer image below)

[Data Frame with multilevel index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnIBI.png)

Python is reading the first three columns as index for the dataframe.

I want to reset the index and convert the index into three separate columns.

However, when I use the reset_index on dataframe.

`energy.reset_index(inplace = True)`

I get the following error.

**IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes.**

Comment: It looks like the lowest level index is `NaN`. Maybe you can set it to a value and then run `reset_index()`?

Comment: I tried [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163674/removing-rows-with-nan-in-multiindex-with-duplicates) to get rid of NaN in multilevel index.

However, I get the same error when I tried that.

**IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes.**

Anything else that I can try?

Comment: Can you please post some code that creates this dataframe if you can?

Comment: ```import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np

   energy = pd.ead_excel(r-'\local_path\Energy_indicators.slx', header= 17, skipfooter=38)

energy.head()```

The code I used to create the dataframe from an Excel file

Comment: Apologies how the code looks above, don't know how to format it so that it is not displayed as one line

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer (on SO) that if a level of the MultiIndex
contains **only** *NaN* values then *reset_index* raises just
this exception.

Try to drop each level of MultiIndex **separately**, if it contains
only *NaN* values then maybe with *drop=True* parameter.